# Python терминал Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, консоль, командная-строка

У меня возникла проблема при работе в терминале с помощью Python.
Суть в том что на компьютере, под linux ubuntu, есть 7 скриптов Python которые нужно периодически запускать и выключать. Хочу сделать автоматизацию этого дела одним скриптом Python но не получилось никак, пробовал pexpect, runscript и т.п. но ничто у меня не сработало. Может есть попроще способы?
(Если в ручную то скрипты запускаю с терминала "python script.py")
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Просто bash скрипт не вариант?

Comment: просто shell скрипт создайте, в самом начале шебанг `#!/bin/sh` и далее построчно то, что делаете в консоли, + посмотрите как можно обогатить скрипт проверками запуска

Comment: Покажите, что именно у вас не сработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно только запускать процессы, то [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) вам вполне достаточно.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["python", "script.py"])
```

Эта функция запускает процесс `python` с аргументом `script.py` и ждёт завершения порождённого процесса.

Comment: Работает! Спасибо. У меня ещё вопрос, а если я закрою этот скрипт, то вызваные им скрипты тоже закроются?

Comment: @AleksandrKholod Скрипт запускает процессы один за другим. Если вы его прибьёте, то те процессы, которые уже выполнились, они уже выполнились. Тот, который выполняется в момент убийства, тоже убьётся. А те, которые ещё не запущены, соответственно не запустятся

Comment: @PakUula это зависит от того, кто владеет контрольным терминалом. А сам ответ  — конечно эе хак, который не стоит делать. Правильнее создать соответствующие функции и вызывать их через `if __main__ == 'main':` (или как-то так) в самих скриптах и из диспетчера.